# Creating a 2 layer background image in CSS

Tags: css, image, background, wallpaper

I'm having some trouble wrapping my head around this.

I would like to have a solid red bar (about 200px wide) running the entire length of the page. I have this already using a small 200x1px image repeated on the Y.

I'd then like another image to sit on top of this red bar, that will be fixed to a specific position on the page at all times.

I'm not sure how to go about's creating this "Second" wallpaper.

I hope this makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what it sounds you want two background images on your site.  Using the background-image in css, separate each image by a comma.  So it would look like:

```
#background{
    background-image: url(image1.jpg), url(image2.jpg);

}
```

You can find out more [here](http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/).

Answer (score 1):

You can specify multiple backgrounds using CSS3. The first background listed will appear on top, and each background can have its own repeat and position settings.

See the [example at developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_multiple_backgrounds) for further reference.

Demonstration below:

```css
body {
  
  background-image:    url('http://lorempixel.com/100/100/abstract/3/'),  
                       url('http://lorempixel.com/200/1/abstract/2/');
  
  background-repeat:   no-repeat,
                       repeat-y;
  
  background-position: 50px 20px,
                       top left;
  
}
```

Note the [browser compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multibackgrounds) of using multiple backgrounds.

Comment: This works absolute wonders!!! I had no idea you could simply stack background images like this, thank you!